# How do I check the current size of the undo tablespace?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I receive the following error error, when executing a query that returns millions of rows:
`ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 128 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS2'`

The error tells me the name of the undo tablespace that is overflowing.
How do I check the current size of the above named undo tablespace?
Is there a PL/SQL command that returns metadata about a given undo tablespace?

Comment: When you say "a query" presumably you mean an update statement? Or delete?

Comment: @APC Well, technically I'm refreshing a materialized view. So I'm running a `select` statement, and the query results are then pumped into the underlying table as an `update`/`insert` statement behind the scenes.

Comment: Well technically you're changing state and that's why UNDO tablespace is an issue. It wouldn't matter if you were just doing a regular SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.tablespace_name "Tablespace name"
       , total_used_space "Used MB"
       , (t1.total_space - t2.total_used_space) "Free MB"
       , t1.total_space "Total MB"
       , round(100 * ( (t1.total_space - t2.total_used_space)/ t1.total_space))
"Percentage Free"
from (select tablespace_name
             , round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) Total_Space
      from dba_data_files
      group by tablespace_name) t1,
     (select round(sum(bytes)/(1024*1024)) total_used_space
             , tablespace_name
      from dba_segments
      group by tablespace_name) t2
      where t1.tablespace_name = t2.tablespace_name ;
```

Comment: This looks really good, thanks. Unfortunately, I'm getting `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` even when executing just the `t1` subquery alone. Is it different in APEX vs Oracle DB? (I don't understand why it *would* be different ...)

Comment: No, it probably means you're connecting as a user which lacks privileges on DBA views.

Comment: @APC Bingo. Dang. I guess I'll have to harass my internal IT/DBA guys again. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Giffyguy happy to see it helped, good luck with DBA friends :)

Comment: Hi @APC thanks for reacting to the OP's comment so fast, cheers!